# Terraform EC2 Auto Scaling with EC2 instances that are already build and running

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, autoscaling

I want to use Terraform to deploy AWS Auto Scaling for a number of EC2 Linux instances that are already build and running.

Can I do this with Terraform or Terraform only allows to create AWS autoscaling using new EC2 instances only?

Answer (score 0):

To address your issue I used [Terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer/blob/master/docs/aws.md) to import existing resources to the Terraform state. In your case you can import EC2 instances and an autoscaling group using this command:

> terraformer import aws --resources=ec2_instance,auto_scaling
> --regions=your-region

Comment: While this answer is correct and Terraformer can be used, Terraform [also provides import functionality natively](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/import).  [Here is the page for the AWS Autoscaling resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_group).